# QPainter not active

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

The following code results in a bunch of errors:

```
void MainWindow::displayBoard()
{
    QPixmap pix(0,0);
    pix.fill(Qt::white);
    QPainter painter(&pix);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
            painter.drawRect(row * 10, col * 10, 10, 10);
    ui->label->setPixmap(pix);
}
```

The errors:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The problem may be that your pixmap is of size 0x0

Comment: @Colin yup that was it thanks! Want to try entering it as an answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that, as Colin pointed out, `pix` was size zero.